# Does passing data from blade to vue component is safe from hackers?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I want to know if it's safe to pass data from blade to vue component knowing that we can see the code in source code.Example:

```
<project 
    id="{{$project->id}}"
    title="{{$project->title}}"
    desc="{{$project->desc}}">
</project>
```

Do users or people with bad intentions can change these in client? If yes what can I do to protect my website? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Can the data be changed by a user? **Yes.**
- Can you stop users from changing the data? **No.**

Vue is JavaScript and JavaScript is ran on the client side. You have no way of stopping a user from changing code on the client side.

The best thing you can do is never trust any input that is sent back to the server. ALWAYS check if the data that has been sent to the server is valid. This is not only true for JavaScript, but any data that is being sent to your server.

Comment: Laravel blade will render the HTML with the passed in PHP variables, so the data cannot be changed by the user

Comment: So you are telling me that I cannot open the development tools and start changing JavaScript variables?

Comment: If Vue is compiled in Production settings, then the variables cannot be changed. Especially, when this is a sub-component, you cannot change those v-attributes with Dev console, unless someone enables Debug Mode, and allow Vue Devtools, which do not happen in Production.

Comment: Sure, I cannot use Vue development tools. But it's still JavaScript, so I can use my browers' built-in JavaScript debug tools. :)

Comment: Those are Vue Props, you cannot change the value of props ... even if you manage to change them, Vue will not take it properly

Comment: Thanks for your answer you two :) . I don't know who is right but it help a bit.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is safe. The blade is rendered together , and then the data is part of the HTML/CSS/JS when rendered. And project component will be rendered into Vue HTML, so the data passed is hidden as well.